# Filebeat dies after trying to harvest 3 times (max_retries)

Tags: filebeat, graylog, elastic-beats

I have set up Filebeat to ship the logs to Graylog by configuring Beats input in Graylog using 5044 port (same as logstash). I received successfully the logs in Graylog. However, if a log file does not change after 3 retries, filebeat dies and I have to start manually to continue with harvesting.

This is the log in Filebeat before it dies (this fragment appears three times in total):

```
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] input/input.go:152      Run input
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:174        Start next scan
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /app/logs/A/api.log
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /app/logs/A/api.log, offset: 2922198
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:548        File didn't change: /app/logs/A/api.log

2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /app/logs/B/api.log
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /app/logs/B/api.log, offset: 28149
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:548        File didn't change: /app/logs/B/api.log

2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /app/logs/C/api.log
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /app/logs/C/api.log, offset: 37930655
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:546        Harvester for file is still running: /app/logs/C/api.log

2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:404        Check file for harvesting: /app/logs/D/api.log
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:494        Update existing file for harvesting: /app/logs/D/api.log, offset: 173342
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:548        File didn't change: /app/logs/D/api.log
2019-04-18T17:09:54.324-0700    DEBUG   [input] log/input.go:195        input states cleaned up. Before: 4, After: 4, Pending: 0
```

In filebeat.yml this is the configuration for process in port 5044. I changed in filebeat.yml max_retries:3 to -1 (infinite) as follows:

```
#----------------------------- Logstash output --------------------------------
output.logstash:
  # The Logstash hosts
  hosts: ["log1.cgi-dev.ca:5044"]

  # Optional SSL. By default is off.
  # List of root certificates for HTTPS server verifications
  #ssl.certificate_authorities: 

  # Certificate for SSL client authentication
  #ssl.certificate: 

  # Client Certificate Key
  #ssl.key: 

  # The number of times to retry publishing an event after a publishing failure.
  # After the specified number of retries, the events are typically dropped.
  # Some Beats, such as Filebeat and Winlogbeat, ignore the max_retries setting
  # and retry until all events are published.  Set max_retries to a value less
  # than 0 to retry until all events are published. The default is 3.
  max_retries: -1
```

As I mentioned, I get the logs from filebeat successfully in Graylog, but when the log file does not change for a time, the filebeat process dies. What would be the culprit to cause Filebeat to die?

Thanks

Comment: The `max_retries` is for the `output.logstash` and not the file harvesting. What is slightly confusing me is that the offset of the file is varying so much. Is there anything special to that file (mounted over the network, lots of writes and file rotations,...)?

Comment: Thanks @xeraa, the file rotation is once a day and it is mounted in the hard disk of the server. However, filebeat is installed in a different server than Graylog. It is very weird, but after restarting again filebeat with -1 as value, it has been up for one hour even thought the log file has not changed and filebeat has retried more than 3 times to infinite. It seems the change worked. I will let you know how it behaves during the day. Thanks again

Comment: That is actually the expected behavior. Filebeat should be monitoring the files / folders and forward any new lines. No special configuration required for that.